# Find equation of circle with reduced radius

Tags: circles

The question is:

> A circle has the equation ${(x - 3)^2 + (y + 9)^2 = 144}$.  A smaller
>   concentric circle has a radius one-third that of the larger one.  Find
>   the equation of the smaller circle.

So I would have thought that the radius of the smaller circle would be $\frac {144}{3} = 48$

But the answer to the question is $(x - 3)^2 + (y + 9)^2 = 16$

Which is one third of $\sqrt{144}$, i.e $12$.

Why is it not a third of $144$?

Comment: What's the **Radius** of the larger circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius of the first circle is not $144$, but $\sqrt{144}=12$. So, the radius of the smaller circle is $r=12/3=4$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, the given circle $(x-3)^2+(y+9)^2=144$ or $(x-3)^2+(y+9)^2=(12)^2$ has center at $(3, -9)$ & a radius $12$

Since, the smaller circle is concentric so its center is at $(3, -9)$ & its radius $=\frac{1}{3}\times \text{(radius of larger circle)}=\frac{1}{3}\times (12)=4$

Hence, the equation of smaller circle $$(x-3)^2+(y+9)^2=(4)^2$$
$$\color{red}{(x-3)^2+(y+9)^2=16}$$